# Symfony2 Facebook connect - redirect after login using js sdk

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk, symfony-2.1

I am implementing Facebook connect on my Symfony2.1 company's website, using the javascript sdk.

The following code that I am using, works fine:

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId  : 'my-app-id', // App ID
            cookie : true,
            xfbml  : true,
            oauth  : true
        });
    };

    function after_click() {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                window.location = "{{ hwi_oauth_login_url('facebook') }}";
            }
        });
    }

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { window.fbAsyncInit(); return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.onload = window.fbAsyncInit;
        js.src = '//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js';
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));
</script>

<div class="fb-login-button m_y" scope="email,user_birthday" onlogin="after_click()"></div>
```

The problem I am facing is that I am desperatly looking for a way to redirect the user to the current page after he logs in. Now the behavior is that the user is always redirected to the homepage of my website.

I know there is a redirect-uri parameter when using the php sdk, I'm looking for something similar with js sdk and I have to say I'm having a hard time finding it.

The `window.location = "{{ hwi_oauth_login_url('facebook') }}";` comes from the Symfony2 OAuth Bundle and is used to manage the Facebook connection. Maybe I need to tell the OAuth Bundle where to redirect after a successful login, but can't really find a solution for that either.

Thanks for any thoughts you can have.

Comment: Why not just use `location.reload()`?

Comment: Well I need to use `window.location = "{{ hwi_oauth_login_url('facebook') }}";` to actually validate the FB authentication process and connect the user to my website

Comment: You could append the current URL to that address (client-side), and then redirect back from there once you’ve processed the login.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it was actually quite simple, just adding `use_referer: true` in my security.yml did the job:

```
security:
    ...
    firewalls:
        portal_area:
            ...
            oauth:
                resource_owners:
                    facebook:      "/login/check-facebook"
                login_path:        /connect
                failure_path:      /connect
                always_use_default_target_path: false
                default_target_path: /
                target_path_parameter: _target_path
                use_referer: true
```

Solved.